# Convert "2020-09-14T14:04:43.123+0000" to Datetime in format "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS" and add minutes in XQuery

Tags: datetime, xquery

How convert "2020-09-14T14:04:43.123+0000" to Datetime "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS" and add minutes in XQuery.

Comment: Why is `YYYY-MM-DD` a Datetime? I don't see any time in there.

Comment: updated "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS" thanks

Comment: This might be a bit tricky, the part `2020-09-14T14:04:43.123` is right for the `xs:dateTime` constructor but the timezone suffix `+0000` is not in the right format for that constructor. Add minutes to an `xs:dateTime` can be solved by adding an `xs:dayTimeDuration`. Formatting an `xs:dateTime` is done with `format-dateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the used dateTime format to the one the `xs:dateTime` constructor functions expects you could insert a colon:

```
xs:dateTime("2020-09-14T14:04:43.123+0000" => replace('([0-9)][0-9])([0-9][0-9])$', '$1:$2'))
```

To add some minutes add an `xs:dayTimeDuration` with the right `M` (minutes) component e.g.

```
xs:dateTime("2020-09-14T14:04:43.123+0000" => replace('([0-9)][0-9])([0-9][0-9])$', '$1:$2')) + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT12M')
```

To format construct the right picture string for `format-dateTime` e.g.:

```
format-dateTime(xs:dateTime("2020-09-14T14:04:43.123+0000" => replace('([0-9)][0-9])([0-9][0-9])$', '$1:$2')) + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT12M'), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01] [H01]24:[m01]:[s01]')
```